# Determining $H^i(\Bbb{R}P^n)$ using a long exact sequence with the double cover or $\Bbb{R}P^n$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

I want to show that  $$H^i(\mathbb{R}P^n; \mathbb{Z_2}) = \begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z_2} \quad 0 \leq i \leq n \\~\\
0 \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Using the fact that $S^n$ is the double cover of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ and there is a long exact sequence

$$ \cdots \rightarrow H^i(\mathbb{R}P^n;\mathbb{Z_2}) \rightarrow H^i(S^n;\mathbb{Z_2}) \rightarrow H^i(\mathbb{R}P^n;\mathbb{Z_2}) \rightarrow H^{i+1}(\mathbb{R}P^n;\mathbb{Z_2}) \rightarrow \cdots  $$

I know that
$$H^i(S^n;\mathbb{Z_2}) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z_2} \quad i = 0,n \\~\\
0 \quad \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
but don't know how to continue. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Here's a hint: for $0<i<n-1$, your LES looks like
$$0\longrightarrow H^i(\Bbb R P^n;\Bbb Z_2)\longrightarrow H^{i+1}(\Bbb RP^n;\Bbb Z_2)\longrightarrow 0,$$
so $H^i(\Bbb R P^n;\Bbb Z_2)\cong H^{i+1}(\Bbb RP^n;\Bbb Z_2)$ for these $i$ values. Can you figure out what goes on at the edges of this set of $i$?

Comment: @Glare Oh that makes perfect sense. For the edges, I believe since we have an injective and surjective map coming in/out of $H^i(S^n)$ and into/out of $H^i(\mathbb{R}P^n)$ on both sides, then there is an isomorphism giving the desired result.